# Datat Table.js How to Check Column Fixed or not?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to check a column fixed or not in Datatable.js for a given column index ?

Currently I am using Data table Fixed Plugin

Comment: Are you using [DataTable Fixed Column](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/) plugin?

Comment: Please note! this is not a good question. Please add more information to it to narrow the problem. And also add *what have you tried so far?*.

Comment: @mmushtaq Yes I am using fixed column plugin

Answer (score 0):

In [DataTable Fixed Column Extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/), every fixed column has `data-dt-row` and `data-dt-column` attributes. By using these, you can get Column Index of those columns which are fixed.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/utprnxba/) I have created a jsFiddler for it.